# how to send attach a file from firebase storage and send it to an email using mailgun services in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, mailgun

Is it possible to attach a file from the firebase storage??
I tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
var mailgun = require("mailgun-js");
var api_key = 'key-acf9f881e32c85b3c0dad34358507a95';
var DOMAIN = 'sandbox76c6f74ddab14862816390c16f37a272.mailgun.org';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: DOMAIN});
var path = require("path");

var filepath = path.join(`gs://i-m-here-c01f6.appspot.com/Groups/${leaderId}`, 'group_image.jpg');


var data = {
    from: 'Excited User <postmaster@sandbox76c6f74ddab14862816390c16f37a272.mailgun.org>',
    to: 'rayteamstudio@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Complex',
    text: 'Group Creation Request',
    html: `<p>A user named: ${fromName} wants to create a group.<br />
            User ID: ${leaderId}<br />
            Group Name: ${groupName}<br />
            Group Description: ${groupDescription}<br /><br />
            To Accept the request click here:<br />
            https://us-central1-i-m-here-c01f6.cloudfunctions.net/acceptOrDenyGroupCreation?leaderID=${leaderId}&requestStatus=approved <br /><br />
            To Deny the request click here:<br />
            https://us-central1-i-m-here-c01f6.cloudfunctions.net/acceptOrDenyGroupCreation?leaderID=${leaderId}&requestStatus=denied /></p>`,
    attachment: filepath
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    if(error)
        console.log('email err: ',error);
});
```

please help

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a `gs://bucket-name/path-to-file` URL to download a file from Cloud Storage just like it was an HTTP URL.  Instead, you'll have to do one of these:

1. Use the Cloud Storage SDK to download the file locally, then attach it to your email
2. Or, use the Cloud Storage SDK to generate a "[Signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)", which will give you an HTTPS URL to the file, which can be used to download it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it as a buffer and send it like this :

```
var request = require('request');
var file = request("https://www.google.ca/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");

var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'serobnic@mail.ru',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!',
  attachment: file
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

from [here](https://bojand.github.io/mailgun-js/#/attach)

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've given you are using the `gs:://bucket-name/path` to download the file from Cloud Storage and send it as an attachment. In order to do so, you would need to use the [request](https://github.com/request/request) dependency as per the docs:

https://github.com/bojand/mailgun-js#attachments

In this case, all you would have to do is:

```
// var path = require("path");
const request = require('request');

var filepath = request(`gs://i-m-here-c01f6.appspot.com/Groups/${leaderId}`);
```

If you wanted to get more specific about assigning properties to the file, you can use the `new mailgun.Attachments(options)` to pass in an `options` parameter that looks something like this:

```
options: {
  data: filepath,
  filename: 'name,jpg',
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  knownLength: 2019121,
};
```

Where

- data - can be one of:

  - a string representing file path to the attachment
  - a buffer of file data
  - an instance of Stream which means it is a readable stream.
- filename - the file name to be used for the attachment. Default is 'file'
- contentType - the content type. Required for case of Stream data. Ex. image/jpeg.
- knownLength - the content length in bytes. Required for case of Stream data.

Answer (score 0):

**[That's an example for Nodemailer, it took me so much time to attach dynamically an attachment from a Cloud Storage for Firebase. Therefore, hopefully it'll help out someone. You can find so many similarities.**

All the examples are in `Angular` / `TypeScript`.

It starts somewhere in the **component.html** file

```
<form
  #formDirective="ngForm"
  [formGroup]="contactForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm.value, formDirective)"
>
  <mat-form-field>
    <ngx-mat-file-input
      (change)="uploadFile($event)"
      formControlName="fileUploader"
      multiple
      type="file"
    >
    </ngx-mat-file-input>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

In **component.ts**

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {
  AngularFireStorage,
  AngularFireStorageReference,
  AngularFireUploadTask,
} from '@angular/fire/storage';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormGroupDirective,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
...

constructor(
  private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
  private angularFireStorage: AngularFireStorage,
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {}

public contentType: string[] = [];
public downloadURL: string[] = [];
public fileName: string = '';
public maxFileSize = 20971520;

public contactForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  fileUploader: [
    '',
    Validators.compose([
      // Your validators rules...
    ]),
  ],
  ...
});
...

public onSubmit(form: any, formDirective: FormGroupDirective): void {
  form.contentType = this.contentType;
  form.fileUploader = this.downloadURL;
  form.fileName = this.fileName;

  this.angularFirestore
    .collection(String(process.env.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_MESSAGES)) // Make sure the environmental variable is a string.
    .add(form)
    .then(() => {
      // Your logic, such as alert...
    .catch(() => {
      // Your error handling logic...  
    });
}

public uploadFile(event: any): void {
  // Iterate through all uploaded files.
  for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
    const file = event.target.files[i]; // Get each uploaded file.
    const fileName = file.name + '_' + Date.now(); // It makes sure files with the same name will be uploaded more than once and each of them will have unique ID, showing date (in milliseconds) of the upload.

    this.contentType = file.type;
    this.fileName = fileName;

    // Get file reference.
    const fileRef: AngularFireStorageReference = this.angularFireStorage.ref(
      fileName
    );

    // Create upload task.
    const task: AngularFireUploadTask = this.angularFireStorage.upload(
      fileName,
      file,
      file.type
    );

    // Upload file to Cloud Firestore.
    task
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((downloadURL: string) => {
            this.angularFirestore
              .collection(String(process.env.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_FILES)) // Make sure the environmental variable is a string.
              .add({ downloadURL: downloadURL });
            this.downloadURL.push(downloadURL);
          });
        }),
        catchError((error: any) => {
          return throwError(error);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

That's all frontend, now it's finally time for our backend.

```
import { DocumentSnapshot } from 'firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore';
import { EventContext } from 'firebase-functions';

async function onCreateSendEmail(
  snap: DocumentSnapshot,
  _context: EventContext
) {
  try {
    const contactFormData = snap.data();

    // You can use those to debug your code...
    console.log('Submitted contact form: ', contactFormData);
    console.log('context: ', _context); // This log will be shown in Firebase Functions logs.

    const mailTransport: Mail = nodemailer.createTransport({
      // Make sure the environmental variables have proper typings.
      host: String(process.env.MAIL_HOST),
      port: Number(process.env.MAIL_PORT),
      auth: {
        user: String(process.env.MAIL_ACCOUNT),
        pass: String(process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD),
      },
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false, //! Fix ERROR "Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames".
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      attachments: [
        {
          contentType: `${contactFormData!.contentType}`,
          filename: `${contactFormData!.fileName}`,
          path: `${contactFormData!.fileUploader}`,
        },
      ],
      ... // Your other mails options such as bcc, from, to, subject, html...
    };

    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

That's more or less all the headache from frontend to backend a developer has to go through to dynamically attach file to an email with correct `contentType`, `downloadURL`, and `fileName`. I was missing a complete solution for the case across WWW, that's why the front-to-back answer.

**Note:**
The frontend is handling multiple file uploads on the UI/Cloud Storage for Firebase side and all the files are uploaded to Firebase. However, only one dynamically added attachment is working fine. I still can't figure out how to handle multiple dynamic files uploads.