# How To Download a File from Firebase Storage to Attach To a Sendgrid Email in Node.js and Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, sendgrid

**EDITED**

I am trying to attach a file stored in Firebase Storage to an email I am sending through Sendgrid. The file sends via email but when I open the PDF all of the pages are blank. The file size and number of pages is correct it's just shows white pages. I found the following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197728/how-to-send-attach-a-file-from-firebase-storage-and-send-it-to-an-email-using-ma) on this but the npm package request has been deprecated. I chose Axios as a replacement. I believe the issue is coming from the way I am Buffering the file. Specifically the line below in index.js.

```
content: Buffer.from(file, 'binary').toString('base64'),
```

The email is being trigger on a Firebase Function onCreate in index.js. The download URL from firebase Storage is received in the snap from the onCreate and then the following email and attachment are created and sent. The sendgrid.js file is just simplifies the email send into a function. And insight on an option that delivers a file that is not corrupt would be appreciated.

sendgrid.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const sendgridKey = functions.config().sendgrid.key
const sgSenderAddress = 'hello@hello.com'

sgMail.setApiKey(sendgridKey)

const templates = {
    welcome: 'd-1111',
}

exports.sendEmail = async ({ to, subject, template = 'welcome', dynamic_template_data, attachments, }) => {
        const mail = {
            to,
            from: sgSenderAddress,
            templateId: templates[template],
            subject,
            dynamic_template_data: { ...dynamic_template_data, support_url: '' },
            attachments: attachments,
        }

        await sgMail
            .send(mail)
            .then(() => functions.logger.log('Email Sent'))
            .catch(error => functions.logger.error(error))
}
```

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const { sendEmail } = require('./libs/sendgrid')
const axios = require('axios')


exports.userOnCreate = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const data = snap.data()

        const { url } = data // This is the download URL from Firebase Storage

        if (url) {
            try {
                const file = await getFileFromStorage(url)
                await sendEmailWithAttachment(file, filename, type, disposition)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    })

const getFileFromStorage = async downloadURL => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(downloadURL, { responseType: 'arrayBuffer' }) //
        return response.data
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching file:', error)
        throw error
    }
}

const sendEmailWithAttachment = async (file, filename, type, disposition) => {
    const attachments = [
        {
            content: Buffer.from(file, 'binary').toString('base64'),
            filename: 'file.pdf',
            type: 'application/pdf',
            disposition: 'attachment',
        },
    ]

    try {
        await sendEmail({
            to: 'goodbye@goodbye.com',
            template: 'welcome',
            dynamic_template_data: {
                subject: 'Welcome To World',
                businessName: 'World',
                action_url: '',
            },
            attachments: attachments,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupt"?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what exactly you're getting.  Have you examined the contents of the file?  What does it contain?  How big is it?  How does it compare to the contents of the source file?

Comment: My apologies. I just updated the code and description to give more information.